# which method allow resharper to transfer method body

Tags: c#

What functionality in resharper allows to transfer a method's body into the body of its callers and remove the method altogether?

```
Copy Type
Inline Method
Encapsulate Field
Inline Field
```

Comment: Is it quiz? We should pick one correct here?

Comment: Did you try them all to see what they did? It's the best way to learn the difference.

Answer (score 1):

That's "Refactor" -> "Inline" - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> on the method name with the default IDEA shortcuts.